# How can i resize the buttons with CSS using input type="number"

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS for the element shown in the attached image.

```
.ClsInpBestAnz {
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 10px;
    width: 45px;
    color: #822;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

How can i resize the buttons?

[image]

Thank you for your help..

Comment: can you provide the html code of the target element?

Comment: <input onchange="showPrice(this,'FA0204A','20209'); 
   vorMerken(event,'FA0204A')" title="Angabe in Lfm" min="0" value="0" class="ClsInpBestAnz" id="bestAnz_FA0204A" name="bestAnz_FA0204A" size="1" type="Number">

Comment: Does it render the same across all browsers Chrome, Firefox? The way I see it, this could be an issue with IE

Comment: I trie d out it works in goole chome but not in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: @MihirKale Nope, IE or Edge don't have this problem, they don't show the buttons at all ; ). The problem occurs in FF at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the updated css here

```
.ClsInpBestAnz {
        border-radius: 0px;
        margin: 5px 15px 0px 10px;
        width: 50px;
        color: #822;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajrek251/

Alternatively, you can take a look at the [Jquery UI spinner](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/) plugin.